# Using PHP - MySQL for MMORPG

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, flash

If I were to store video game data from flash to a MySQL database using PHP commands that I loaded by visiting arbitrary web-pages in an iFrame on my site and I was triggering loading those pages from flash via javascript would this begin to slow down the speed of my MMORPG's real-time use (lag) any more than just using a traditional game server? Would the difference be insignificant to the point where I can keep coding in the languages I already know or should I set-up a server and learn some SDK's language for it?

Comment: I feel like I wouldn't want to play this game. It sounds messy.

Comment: Don't worry about it unless it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading/saving data for Flash through an IFRAME is an incredibly roundabout way of doing things. ActionScript can make HTTP requests directly. Depending on what version of ActionScript you're using:

1. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000575.html
2. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00003121.html
3. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html